# I want to put data into a new file using shell

Tags: linux, shell

So, I have a shell script and it gets some variables from different files like name and filesize. I want to put all that data into a new file and save it.
I tried using `echo "filename": " ${name} ," > newfile.json`. It creates the file but don't put any data to it.

Comment: What do you have in the file ? What is the value of $name, what are you expecting ?

Comment: @Priyanshu : How did you verify this? Even if the variables `filename` and `name` would be empty, `newfile.json` would contain at least the string `:  ,`.

Comment: Yes it was putting just : in the file, with the answer below i was able to insert all the data inside the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "data" >> file
```